# How can I modify the Divi layout via php files?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Divi Wordpress and I wanted to add some extra markup. I added the extra markup in header.php but It's not appearing in any other page other than the homepage.

I went ahead and modified the other files (index.php, single.php, page.php) but nothing is happening.

Funny thing is that I searched the files for the current markup that is generated. I found a couple of files and modified them but nothing. I even deleted those files but nothing is happening!

How the hell is Wordpress generating that markup if it has no files that contain such a markup?

The homepage immediately knows that something is wrong (no files) but the other pages are not.

If I delete the whole divi folder, the css is gone but the markup is still generated by some divi files.

What black magic is this :)?

And yes, I forced refresh, tried another browser and restarted XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The wordpress installation was cloned from a previous one. It seems that the files were used from that installation, so I could edit the php files untill tomorrow. Strange!